# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ,

Tags: react-native

*I got this error:
`Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ,` 
I searched on web  and I tried but nothing solved. Also I dont see any mistake here*

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
          }),
      body: JSON.stringify(collection) // <-- Post parameters
      })
      .then((response) =>  response.text())
      .then(leaders => {
          console.log(leaders);
  }
}   <---- here  it gives error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(collection), // <-- Post parameters
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((leaders) => {
        console.log(leaders);
      }); // << here's your issue ... missing `)`
```

**SUGGESTION**

Use `async-await` syntax for more readaable and easy to debug `async code`